# Sparx Enterprise Architect conversion (from source to UML)

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect, auto-generate

I need to make a UML class diagram for a project. I used Sparx Enterprise Architect in the past to generate source code from a diagram so I'm using that.

The project is complete so all of the code is done and I don't really want to write all the classes/functions manually, so I was trying to generate the diagram from the source code but can't seem to find a way to do it. I searched online and on their website but nothing.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What value do you think you are adding by doing this? I'd stick to a package diagram showing responsibilities in modules, and use something like doxygen for documenting the project as built.

Comment: I just did it because I had to (and no one told me beforehand). I always document projects with doxygen though.

Comment: I am not sure that makes much sense; Doxygen can generated UML style class diagrams.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's called "[reverse engineering](http://www.sparxsystems.com/uml_tool_guide/code_engineering/reverseengineersourcecode.htm)" to import the code into the model. After it's in the model you can make diagrams.

Comment: The reverse engineering concept is nice but the reality is different !! If you look in detail at the model then you will realize that less of 50% of the project has been really mapped to the model. I tried java reverse but other reverses could be better.

Comment: Even worth because because if you generate code from your model and then recreate a model from your code you have lost 70% of the initial class diagram model !! 
The problem is that there no traceability between model and code generation. Only EclipseUML Omondo allows this feature because they have a merge option.

Comment: @roko-sifredi -- Some years ago I found that Sparx Enterprise Architect worked well for round-trip engineering, using C#.

Comment: It's ok, thanks. It didn't work that well but I didn't expect it to. I just didn't want to write all the classes/functions again so it worked fine. I just added the connections manually and cleaned up the extra stuff that came up.

Answer (score 10):

For Version 8 of EA Corporate Edition.
Open or create a project.
Create empty class diagram.
Menu selection:
Project -> Source Code Engineering -> Import  Files
Directory dialogue box opens for you to select files.

I have 'reverse engineered' many C++ projects, large and small. You WILL spend significant time on cleaning up. It will depend on the quality of the project, its structure and code.

Then you can generate a documentation report on it (Project->Documentation) which I have found very useful, the HTML report, to navigate the code.

Answer (score 1):

for that you should first use Reverse Engineering options but as some other users pointed out, this is not a strenght from EA. i tried in the past (version 7.3 I think) to do it with C, Python and Java Projects and the results were not always satisfactory.

I dont know which programming language is your code written in, but as for C, if you use preprocessor instructions, you will have lot of issues and incompatibilities in the result.